# Javascript object getter

Tags: javascript, object, getter

I tried to execute this small part of code in my browser console:

```js
a = {b: 1}
Object.defineProperty(a, 'b', { get: function() { console.log(5); } })
c = a.b
c
c
```

Everytime i used to call 'c' varaible, i am not getting console.log(5) to be executed. That means my getter is not calling.
I think that might be because i am not calling a.b directly but using c variable instead.
Can someone confirm/reject my thoughts ? Also how can i make it call getter everytime i am calling 'c' ?

Thanks.

Comment: You have `a.b` assigned to `c`. That is when your getter in invoked. And once the get value is assigned to `c`. `c` behaves like any other variable.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone confirm/reject my thoughts

You will get `console.log(5)` run every time when you call `a.b`. But when you use `c = a.b`, this runs the `getter` function, copies the result into the `c` (which is `undefined`) and starting from here `c` has its independent value which is returned via `a.b`. So after this every time when you call `c`, you evaluate `c` and get the value of it, not the `a.b`. In few words `c` has nothing anymore with `a.b`.

> Also how can i make it call getter everytime i am calling 'c' ?

Actually there is no solution. One thing you can do is returning a function which logs the result, but now you will need to invoke `c` to get it work. Maybe you can chagne your logic in somewhere, so this is not a good workaround.

```js
const a = {b: 1}
Object.defineProperty(a, 'b', { get: function() { 
      console.log(5); 
      return () => console.log(5);
   } 
});
const c = a.b;
c();
c();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only `get`ting `b` once, and assigning the returned value, in this case `undefined`, to `c`.

The getter is not called anymore if you work with `c` after that.